# How to test pairs of numbers in one Array with a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

How to test a pair of numbers in one array?

like

```
const arr = [1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 12]
```

I want to test 1 and 3, 3 and 5, 5 and 9, 9 and 11, 11 and 12.

```
for (let i= 0; arr.length > i; i++){
  for (let j=0; arr.length > j; j++){
        console.log(arr[i], arr[j])


}}
```

How does the douple for loop needs to look like in javascript.

Comment: You only need one loop. Loop from 0 to length - 2 and  compare `arr[i]` with `arr[i+1]`

Comment: The loop should use `i < arr.length-1`. You need to stop before the last element, so that `i+` is still valid.

Comment: Something like: `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
}`

Comment: how do i handle the last element when I make it with one loop?

Comment: @SeverinKoch did you try running above code?If you do then you can see the expected output. For instance: https://codepen.io/mandy8055/pen/RwvRava

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @gog, you can achieve the pair testing in an array with a single loop. Just iterate from 0 to length - 2 and compare arr[i] with arr[i+1].

To do this, use the loop condition i < arr.length - 1. This approach ensures you stop just before the last element, allowing for valid pair comparisons between adjacent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply using a "sliding window" technique:

```
for(let i = 0, max = arr.length - 1; i < max; i += 1) {
  const first = arr[i];
  const second = arr[i + 1];

  // do something with first and second
}
```

You can even generalize it:

```
function slidingWindow(size, callback) {
  const lengthOffset = size - 1;
  for(let i = 0, max = arr.length - lengthOffset; i < max; i += 1){
    const slide = arr.slice(i, i + size);
    callback(slide, i, arr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an inner loop:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 12]

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  console.log(`${arr[i - 1]} and ${arr[i]}`);
}
```